# Only Call a Function if another Function does not return None

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception

So I am working on an assignment that requires me to work on two separate python files, one with my main code, and another with two functions, one that encrypts a file, another one that decrypts it. This is what the main code file looks like:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\gabri\\Desktop\\CS\\Assignment 7')

from assgn7 import encrypt_file, decrypt_file

file_in = 'Sample.txt'
print('Encrypting input file', file_in)
enc_dict = encrypt_file(file_in)

print('-' * 20)

print('Decrypting input file', file_in)
decrypt_file(enc_dict, file_in + '.enc')
```

I am supposed to modify this code so that `decrypt_file()` is called only if `encrypt_file()` does not return `None`.

How can I go about this? I was thinking of maybe using exception handling but didn't know what kind of error this would need to catch.

Comment: As for using an exception, you need know what exception `decrypt_file` raises in that condition. You could look at its docs, look at its source code or just try it once to see what happens - that last one is less robust but its what I'd do.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the returned object

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\gabri\\Desktop\\CS\\Assignment 7')

from assgn7 import encrypt_file, decrypt_file

file_in = 'Sample.txt'
print('Encrypting input file', file_in)
enc_dict = encrypt_file(file_in)
if enc_dict is not None:
    print('-' * 20)
    print('Decrypting input file', file_in)
    decrypt_file(enc_dict, file_in + '.enc')
```

Answer (score 0):

in `decrypt_file`, you can terminate function if `enc_dict` is None.

```
def decrypt_file(enc_dict, filein):
   if enc_dict is None:
      return 
   < rest of code >
```